# Load .jpeg and set to JLabel?

Tags: java, image, swing, file-io, jlabel

So I'm doing this assignment for class. I'm suppose to fill a JFrame with 3x3 JLabels randomly with X or Y images. I got some small images off of google and put them in the source folder of my Java project in Eclipse and called them "X.jpeg" and "O.jpeg".

I got this to work when just using strings "X" and "O", but I can't figure out how to get the images to work. Any advice is very much appreciated.

Ok so this is what I'm using now. I'm stuff on adding the Jlabel to the JFrame as an image!!!!

> Blockquote

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Chapter12_7 extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Chapter12_7 frame = new Chapter12_7();
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setTitle("Chapter12_7");
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public Chapter12_7(){

    BufferedImage x = ImageIO.read(new File("/X.jpeg"));
    BufferedImage o = ImageIO.read(new File("/O.jpeg"));
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
    add(p1);


    int[] ran = new int[9];

    for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
        ran[j] = (int) (Math.random() * 2);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
        if(ran[i] == 0){
            p1.add(new JLabel( x , JLabel.CENTER));
        }
        else
            p1.add(new JLabel( o , JLabel.CENTER));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `new ImageIcon("X.jpeg");`, this assumes that the `X.jpeg` is a file that exists on the HD within the same context as the where you executed the program from.  `ImageIcon` also does not throw any exceptions if something goes wrong, which is very annoying.

If the files are stored within the Jar file, then you need to use `getClass().getResource("/X.jpeg")` instead.

You should also use `ImageIO.read` to read the images.  This will (amongst other things) throw an exception if it can't read the images.

Have a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

Also, I believe that in Eclipse, the resources should be stored in the resources folder, these will be automatically added to your application Jar. I'm not sure what will happen if they are in your source directory as I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: So now i'm using BufferedImage to load them, but I'm getting compile errors when I try to add a new JLabel(x) or JLabel(o). JLabel doesn't seem to like the BUfferedImage data type, and keeps suggesting a string.

Comment: Use something like `new JLabel(ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/X.jpeg")));`, you can break it down to individual statements if you wish (which is probably a good idea)